# Young Adult book: rain forest girl leaves her tribe and finds they are all living in a huge dome

Tags: story-identification

I read this young-adult book in the early 90s, but it was probably published in the 70s or 80s. All I remember is this: the book starts with this girl who lives in a tribe in the rain forest, then something happens and she leaves (possibly with other kids from the tribe). She takes a boat really far down the river and she discovers that her tribe, and the forest they live in, is actually a kind of park inside this gigantic dome in a very futuristic city.

I asked about this book on reddit two years ago, but no one could identify it: [Rain forest girl leaves her tribe and learns they are living in a huge dome](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/10z8e5/tomtbook_rain_forest_girl_leaves_her_tribe_and/) (August 2012).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you certain it was [a young girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Truman_Show)?

Comment: @Richard your link not only is not young and not a girl, but he's also not living in a rain forest. And there is no novelization that I know of.

Comment: @MrLister - There's a dome though....

Comment: Yeah, and a boat, I know. But still, if the OP remembers a book, I'm pretty certain it's a book, not a movie.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but it was definitely a book that I read in the early 90s, before "The Truman Show" was filmed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[**Moon-Flash** by Patricia A. McKillip](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19818.Moon_Flash). 1984.

> Kyreol's small world begins at the Face, a high rock cliff, and ends at Fourteen Falls, a series of rapids. Each year, her people celebrate Moon-Flash-a spark of light that seems to come from and go into the moon, a symbol of life and joy. When a mysterious stranger arrives, Kyreol wants to know more about him, as well as the Moon-Flash, and soon she and her childhood friend Terje leave their home to look for answers.

[image]